# Wordpress bootstrap 5 dropdown menu working only on home page

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-5

I´m working on a theme template for my wordpress site.
Menu I´m trying to make is gonna have 1 dropdown, I used codes from multiple githubs and every one was working but only on my front-page so right after I go to another page the dropdown doesn´t work anymore and when I click it just adds # to my url address, also the wordpress admin panel is missing, In addition the bootstrap menu button won't appear after reaching the breakpoint but on my homepage it's fully responsive. So basically, when I leave my homesite it´s all messed up.

I´m using this navwalker: https://github.com/AlexWebLab/bootstrap-5-wordpress-navbar-walker

Thanks for response

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot to add wp_header() to page.php to include js scripts. I didn't know that wordpress adds scripts to footer.

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, this happens because of a plugin conflict. You need to disable the plugins one by one and find which one is causing this issue.

Comment: Unluckily that's not the issue since I'm not using any plugin